# Set up Firebase Crash Reporting in cordova app

Tags: cordova, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

One of our app was crashing in ios so i wanted to add firebase crash reporting,

I added the `cordova-plugin-firebase-crash` plugin and also placed `google-services.json` file in the root as well as project folder.

Then built the app but nothing shows in my firebase console.

Can someone please confirm me the basic steps to adding the crash reporting to my app?

My steps:

1. Added a project in Firebase console
2. Added an app with the id I have in my `config.xml`
3. Added the `cordova-plugin-firebase-crash`
4. Downloaded the `google-services.json` file after setting up for
   android in firebase console and placed in all likely locations
5. Built for android Installed the app in phone

But I see nothing in firebase console. Is it that firebase crash reporting only works with published apps?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Crash Reporting (and Firebase Crashlytics) only reports native Java/JVM exceptions on Android.  If you've built your app with Cordova, that means you're running JavaScript code, which is no longer native.  So none of those errors will be caught by the SDK and reported in the console.

Comment: What about the native code that is written by the cordova plugins, will that not be reported?

Comment: If it's written in JavaScript, likely not.  The errors caught have to be Java exceptions that would crash the app.

Comment: @SamiullahKhan You can always manually log exceptions through the plugin and use the `window.onerror` callback to catch JS exceptions.